# I need a .bat file to delete pdf files

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a bat file that will within a certain folder, delete any pdf file older than 48 hours with a file name that DOESNT have  _TTO  or _OR anywhere in the filename.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: bat files do not have access to determine if a file is older than 48 hours.

Comment: that's fine what I can do is have the bat file run every 48 hours and delete everything with those exceptions to the file name.  So how do i write a bat file to delete all pdfs within a folder that doesnt have _TTO or _OR in the file name

Comment: the bat can run the delete files but there is no "doesn't have" for the delete command. You can delete all files that start with a letter del a*.pdf etc. Basicly you can have the bat file contains the same commands that you would type in at the command prompt.

Comment: @wayne Your comments are misleading, as standard OS tools do exist to do the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's alternative that works in my test:

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\folder" && (
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('forfiles /m *.pdf /d -2 ^|findstr /i /v "_TTO _OR" ') do del %%a
popd
)
```

Comment: this is better than working with `echo @fname`. I had this forgotten already.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, at this moment i can't. Adapt as needed and when the list of files is correct, remove the `echo` to delete the files.

```
set "folder=c:\somewhere"

(  forfiles /p "%folder%" /m *.pdf /d -2 /c "echo @path" 
)| for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('findstr /v /r /c:"\\[^\\]*_TTO[^\\]*$" /c:"\\[^\\]*_OR[^\\]*$" ') do (
    echo del "%%~f"
)
```

It uses `forfiles` to select the list of pdf files older than 2 days inside the defined folder, and filters the list for the filenames not containing any of the indicated substrings.

Comment: I'll give it a try locally see what happens.  thanks, and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Simply With `del` But You Can Try Do It Like This:

```
@echo off
set /p filedel=Enter File Location:
set /p filenamedel=Enter File Name:
cd %filedel%
del %filenamedel%
echo Done
pause
exit
```

Some What Works For Me (TESTED ON WINDOWS 7 HOME PREMIUM,WINDOWS XP PRO,WINDOWS 2000 PRO SERVICE PACK 4,And WINDOWS 98 SE)
EDIT:
You Might Want To Add The Code Below Too:

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0
:--------------------------------------
```

EDIT2:That Was A Start ;D